# How to get array element number?

Tags: javascript

Consider an array:

```
var array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

I need to iterate it and get such alerts:

The 0 value is one

The 1 value is two

The 2 value is three

```
for ( i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  alert( 'The ' + ? + 'value is ' + array[i] );
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not you're trolling us =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 I'm sorry, the question really is not I wanted to be. I simplified it a lot. But because of the answers, now I see, that I have to change script logic, to use nested 'for' loops or something. Thanks to all!

Comment: I hope I didn't offend.  I saw your other (very helpful) answers about javascript / jQuery, and thought you were messing with us =) I get it now.

Comment: Don't bother, it's ok :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `i`, it will be the position.

```
for ( i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
   alert( 'The ' + i + 'value is ' + array[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to alert the position and is associated value, you will need to use `i` to indicate the position, and `array[i]` to indicate value:

```
//Will output "The 0 value is one", "The 1 value is two", ...

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  alert( 'The ' + i + 'value is ' + array[i] );
}
```

Comment: You might of misunderstood, I think he wants ? to be i.

Comment: That's not even valid JavaScript that you posted. edit: it is now that you've changed the `?` to `i`.

Comment: I fixed it, it was a bit of a typo :)

Comment: DV removed.  I think your brain was moving faster than your hands =)

Comment: @Jim, that was part of the typo :)

Comment: Now it just looks like you waited for someone to post the correct answer and copied it. Embarrassing. :D

Comment: So many like it up there already it's not even worth having it around.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i, max;

for ( i=0, max = array.length; i < max; i += 1) {
   alert( 'The ' + i + 'value is ' + array[i] );
}
```

- Declare your **vars** at the beginning. This help to prevent hoisting.
- In order to be more efficient, save the array length, so you don't have to query the array    object every time.
- Use i += 1 instead of i++.

Answer (score 1):

**Please** use a variable to read the length of the array only once.

Also be careful, if you don't use the `var` statement in front of variables in JavaScript, the parser will look for a variable with the same name up in the chain. If you are using a local variable, always declare it with the `var` statement.

```
for ( var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
   alert( 'The ' + i + ' value is ' + array[i] );
}
```